# Как написать ссылку при домене 3 уровня?

Tags: php

У меня есть сайт на котором создал домены 3 уровня. Фактически это папки на сервере в корневом каталоге. index, config, variables находятся в корневом каталоге, остальные файлы в папках. Как написать ссылку на домен 3 уровня в меню? У меня сейчас прописан такой вариант, но это не совсем правильно:

```
 <a class='at' href='/page/p1.php' target='_top'>Page1</a>
 <a class='at' href='/page/p2.php' target='_top'>Page2</a>
 <a class='at' href='/page/p3.php' target='_top'>Page3</a>
 <a class='at' href='www.doman.site.com/page/p1.php' target='_top'>Page1</a>
```

Мне бы хотелось, что бы при смене сервера и домена ссылки работали.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?
// немножко хак
$_ENV['L'] = array(
  'dom'      =>'www.site.com',
  'subdom1'  => 'dmn1.site.com',
  'subdom2'  => 'dmn2.site.com',
  'subdom3'  => 'dmn2.site.com',
  'dirAdmin' => '/admin/pages/',
  'dirInfo'  => '/info/'
  );
?>
```

---

```
<?
// пользуемся
$L = $_ENV['L'];
echo '<a href="http://'.$L['dom'].$L['dirAdmin'].'login.php">Log In</a>';
echo '<a href="http://'.$L['subdom1'].$L['dirInfo'].'">SubDomain #1 info</a>';
echo '<a href="http://'.$L['subdom2'].$L['dirInfo'].'">SubDomain #2 info</a>';
?>
```

Comment: Как только два разных скрипта, которые работают на одном сервере, начинают использовать скрипт, будет весело.

Comment: Хм, а что будет? Даже если без include_once, ну перезапишет он `$_ENV['L']`, и?)

Comment: Первый скрипт начнет использовать переменные второго. Один будет работать правильно, а второй - странно. `$_ENV['L']` распространяется на все скрипты, запущенные текущим интерпретатором.

Comment: Я, конечно, еще проверю, но мне всегда казалось, что это входящий массив (как `$_POST`).

Проверил, входящий. В скрипт *передается* серверный массив переменных окружения, но из скрипта не обновляется. Я просто пользуюсь свойством суперглобальности. Ну и `_ENV` короче и удобнее)

Comment: Ну если каждый раз заполнять, тогда вполне должно работать.

Comment: А не каждый раз запускать скрипт с конфигурацией - это где такое есть?) Тем более массив в переменные окружения я бы не стал писать, он все равно автоматом не сериализуется. в `_ENV` всегда много места и ковырять его семантически вредно, но очень удобно.

Comment: Спасибо! Это немного упрощает работу...
Но думаю, что есть еще варианты без объявления переменных.
Перерыл весь инет пытаясь найти как организовать навигацию, но толком ничего не нашел. Все так сложно. ((((

Comment: Без объявления переменных - только с объявлением констант)) Дописать?

Comment: @Sh4dow "А не каждый раз запускать скрипт с конфигурацией - это где такое есть?)"
я о таком не говорил. Скрипт конфигурации запускать каждый раз не нужно. Нужно только при инсталляции, где он сгенерирует файл конфига.

Comment: Спасибо. Справлюсь. С константами я разобрался... )))

Answer (score 1):

Есть такие варианты:

- писать все ссылки относительными, помня при этом, где какая страница лежит
- завести себе файлик с константами (например `$admin='/myadmin/'; $db='/db/data/'` и подобные. А в коде просто писать `href="'".$adnin."index.html'"`. В таком случае при переезде, нужно будет только откорректировать один файл. При этом, если ссылка на какой то файл повторяется очень часто, то можно сформировать не то что ссылку, а и вместе с href и названием. Это вдобавок сильно может ускорить разработку и уменьшить кол-во ошибок.

Comment: Я этот вариант рассматривал. А как можно использовать супер глобальные переменные, например

    .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].

Как это можно использовать? У меня почему то не получается. Может синтаксическая ошибка какая то... Напишите правильность написания.
Это не единственный способ. Есть много других.

Comment: брр... это писал один человек? Как то несвязанный комментарий.

Comment: Извините, а что не так? Например,

    <a  href='http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/page/p3.php'>Страница 3</a>

или


   <a  href='http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/page/p2.php'>Страница 2</a> 
 

Это должно работать одинаково. Но я не знаю как сделать грамотно.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` задается в настройках апача (или другого вебсервера), `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` - это то, что передалось в http-запросе.
Первое может быть не совсем верно настроено админом (хотя обычно настроено). Второе может быть неверно передано браузером.

Comment: Это все настроено - проверял. И все таки, как грамотно организовать ссылки. Я читал, что лучше использовать глобальные переменные, но не уверен, что это правильно. Как специалисты используют навигацию?

Comment: Не думаю, что использование массива `$_SERVER[]` будет правильно.
Я считаю, что правильно использовать свою глобальную переменную, а вот в скрипте инсталляции смотреть `$_SERVER[]` и выставляет переменную. Именно такое я видел в многих популярных CMS (в том или ином виде).
Ещё одно "за" свою переменную. Представьте, что завтра Вам нужно будет расположить свой сайт не в корне, а в каталоге test. И Вам придется ручками лазить по всему коду и переправлять.

Comment: Еще один вариант нарыл в инете:
http://irbis-team.com/15/9 

а если будет сто страниц - их тоже все надо прописать (в данном скрипте)